# /usr/local/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Hi My python installation is in different directory and i am using a docker image which is mac based and it is referring shebang line as /user/local/bin/python3 from other folder in shell script .

my python installation path

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/myuser/project', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>>
```

so is  there a way without changing the shebang line i can redirect or link to my installation of python3 to get out of this error.

is it recommended to install python3 in given path. ?

please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't modify the shebang of the file, and you have access to the Dockerfile that creates your docker image, you can add a command directive to create a symbolic link: `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/`.
If you don't have access to the Dockerfile. Then you can run the above command from within the running docker instance. That should solve your issue without having to modify the file.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: CMD ["ln -s" , "/usr/bin/python3", "/usr/local/bin/"] should work ? i mean do i need to say     CMD ["ln -s" , "/usr/bin/python3", "/usr/local/bin/pyhon3"]      . i am new  to linux system

Comment: Both ways should work without issue. Assuming python3 is in `/usr/bin/` if you don't know if it's located there, then you can do the following instead: `RUN /bin/bash -c 'ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/'`. Not sure this form would work with `CMD` though.

Comment: Another option is to use: `RUN` instead of `CMD`. Right now I can recall where I read that CMD was preferred. But either `CMD` or `RUN` should work fine.

Comment: Okay I just tried the following in my docker container: `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "ln -s", "$(which python3)", "/usr/local/bin/" ]`  and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could set you shebang to "/usr/bin/env python" as usual, then set your path appropriately so that the correct version of python is on the path for your executable.  In bash you can set the path on the command line using:

```
PATH=python/path:$PATH app
```

I will sometimes ignore the shebang and type `python/path/python $(which app)` in order to control which python interpreter is running.

Comment: Yes this is true however in my case i am using a docker image. And for some reason i cant change that or dont want to change my docker image so for my dev environment purpose , is there any way keeping shebang as  it is , i can make it work ?